# How can I fix indentation in Vim for Jquery scripts?

Tags: jquery, vim, syntax, indentation

I have this portion of the script indented by Vim like this:

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: siteurl + 'ajax/upload',
dataType: 'json',
progress: function (e, data) {
    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
},
start: functuion (e, data) {
},
```

I mean, if I select these lines and press `=` that is what I obtain, while I'd like it to appear like this:

```
$(function () {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: siteurl + 'ajax/upload',
    dataType: 'json',
    progress: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    },
    start: functuion (e, data) {
    },
```

I'm using this [syntax file](https://github.com/vim-scripts/jQuery). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [this JavaScript indent plugin from Ryan Fabella](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1936), and it produces this (which I deem more correct than what you expect):

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: siteurl + 'ajax/upload',
        dataType: 'json',
        progress: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        },
        start: functuion (e, data) {
        },
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is actually what I expected, I just missed to indent the second line and rest followed.